# Is 'at summer night' correct?

Tags: prepositions

> At night in the summer it tends to get cold.

Is it possible to change into 'at summer night'?

Comment: Short answer: No, "at night" can't take an adjective for *night* in the middle like that.  I don't have a good reference or rule for that, though.  You could say "On summer nights..."  Yes, I know that it's very confusing that it's "at night" but "on summer nights".  Sorry, English is weird like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, we use the phrase **at night** as an inseparable *adverbial phrase.* No other word can intervene between **at** and **night** in this usage.

The phrase is idiomatic. An exhaustive treatise on this and related idioms is available **[here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/233169)** at our sister site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it would not be idiomatic. It would be poetic. In everyday English we don't usually want to be poetic.

Both *at night* and *in the summer* are idiomatic expressions.

You certainly *can* put an adjective in between *at* and *night*, and people might even understand what you mean. But you would be departing from the norm.

For instance, it is pretty clear what *at early night* means,   but we don't say this.   We say *at nightfall* or some other expression. Instead of *at late night* we say *late at night*. So *at night* is a tough nut to crack.  Having said that, if you write poetry and include *at summer night*, it could  be appropriate and probably understood; poets often  break the rules and use language in new ways.